# Homework template

Tags: formatting, environments, templates

I've been using this homework template I found online that is pretty light. I am very new to using LaTeX, and although I find writing basic mathematical expressions easy, some of the cooler more complex LaTeX stuff seems way above me. The homework template I found has this in it:

```
\newcounter{prob}
\newenvironment{problem}[1]
{\begin{sloppypar}\stepcounter{prob}\noindent{\large\bfseries Problem %\arabic{prob}
} {\bfseries (#1)}
\begin{quote}}
{\end{quote}\end{sloppypar}}
```

and I have been using this in this way:

```
\begin{problem}{Problem 1}
   ***Problem solution***
\end{problem}
```

However, when I want to include the problem statement, this code introduces too much space. How can I edit my template so that my final results will look like:

**Problem 1**: problem statement *(not bold)*

problem solution

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/5764) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Comment: instead of using `{\bfseries (#1)}`, use `\textbf{(#1)}`.

Comment: @Benjamin : you should look the page 17 of the documentation of `ntheorem` (see for example at the ctan web site). It is an easy way to obtain the formatting you want for problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it: I took out the `\begin{quote}` `\end{quote}`

```
\newcounter{prob}
\newenvironment{problem}[1]
{\begin{sloppypar}\stepcounter{prob}\noindent{\large\bfseries Problem} {\bfseries (#1)}}{\end{sloppypar}}
```