# Recommendation for homework use

Tags: header-footer, texworks, sourcecode, exam

I'm re-discovering LaTeX after an absence of 15-17 years. Sadly all my previous skills are gone so I'm starting from scratch.

I am taking two grad courses for which I have to submit assignments every week which involve embedding mathematical equations and code.

So I thought I'd post a question asking for stuff (code fragments, tools, techniques, ...) I should consider for the stated purpose.

Some things I'm currently researching:

1. What is the best way to embed code (java, R, ...) into my Latex documents?
2. What document type is best suited for these types of homeworks?
3. I typically highlight my answers using a highlighter style or using boxes ... any tips on doing this in LaTeX?
4. I typically have a header in greyed out text on every page which have the homework name, date, my name and my id printed on it ... any tips on doing this?
5. I've discovered TexWorks and I love it ... anything else I should consider?

I read some of the previous posts [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75778/homework-template), [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28079/documentclass-for-homework-problems) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31183/class-file-for-homework-assignments) but didn't get the answers I was looking for.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/) Please only ask **one** distinct question per post! This is necessary for the Q&A format here. This way, other users with similar problems can find the specific problem they're looking for. A question here revolves around one abstract issue (e.g. greying out), not so much its real-life application (e.g. your homework). Please **eliminate all but one** of your questions from this question. You're most welcome to ask the other questions as separate posts (after checking that such questions don't already exist on tex.sx).

Comment: Hi @doncherry, I read your comment and my thinking was that I'd like to find out how people best use LaTex for typesetting their homeworks. And, I feel that there are other folks out there who would have this particular questions. The points (or sub-qeustions) are points that I figure most people using LaTeX for this purpose will find useful. To

Comment: Your questions are definitely useful, and other people may have similar questions. The problem is with the way knowledge management works here. Take for example your fifth question about editors: Assuming it hadn't been asked before, and we get lots of great answers about editors here, each of them also containing responses to your questions 1-4. Then, one day, someone comes along asking a bundled question like yours -- not about homework, but about theses instead; this question has a subquestion about editors, and others about title pages and appendices. [tbc]

Comment: [ctd] Would that question be a duplicate of yours? It certainly wouldn't make sense to have the information about editors spread out in two different questions, even though they information in the answers is going to be exactly the same. Also, homework requirements in LaTeX may not be as uniform as you think they are. I, for one, as a philologist, have never put any source code in any piece of LaTeXed homework; instead, it would be quite natural for me to include a question about numbering of linguistic examples -- which would probably seem quite odd to you. [tbc]

Comment: [ctd] I hope this gives you a better understanding why we like to keep subquestions separate -- which is different from most forums on the net. I'm sure you'll appreciate this aspect of the Stack Exchange system soon. (Also, more questions = more rep ;)

Comment: Hi @doncherry, tied up at the moment, will try to edit the question in a bit. Thanks.

Comment: Sure, thanks! In case your question is closed by then (It currently has three close votes), do still edit it and then write a comment to me, I'll get the reopening started.

Answer (score 6):

Some ideas:

1. The [`listings` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) provides the `lstlisting` code typesetting environment and defines a number of languages, including `Java` and `R`. This is as easy as `\lstset{language=java}`, after which the keyword formatting will automatically be set. Of course, you can modify or improve on this. You can even include external code files using `\lstinputlistings[<options>]{<file>}`. See the [`listings` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf) for more information.
2. The standard document classes have been sufficient for most of my needs. Especially if you're talking about small/short documents, the `article` document class should work. `book` and `report` provides chapters, which you most likely do not need in this instance.
3. This depends on the style of the answers. Are you only presenting a number as an answer? A whole equation? A whole paragraph? You could create an environment that prints **Answer:** followed by the answer.
4. King of headers is [`fancyhdr`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr). Setting the header is associated with a page style, which is easily created using

   ```
   \fancypagestyle{mypagestyle}{%
     \fancyhf{}% Clear all headers/footers
     \fancyhead{<header>}% Header
     \fancyfoot{<footer>}% Footer
     %...
   }
   ```

   Read the [`fancyhdr` documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/fancyhdr/fancyhdr.pdf) for more ideas. You may also require the [`xcolor` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/xcolor) to change the font colour.
5. For a taste of the LaTeX editors out there, see [LaTeX Editors/IDEs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/339/5764).

Comment: I would think that http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2414/4012 also applies to questions that clash with our Q&A format by containing more than one distinct question?

Answer (score 5):

1. You could use the [`listings`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/listings) or [`minted`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/minted) packages.
2. You can use `article` (or `scrartcl`, or `memoir`).
3. You could use the [`framed`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/framed), [`mdframed`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mdframed) ot [`tcolorbox`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) packages; boxes cretaed using the first two admit page breaks.
4. You can use the [`fancyhdr`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyhdr) or the [`titleps`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titleps) packages.

Comment: I would think that http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2414/4012 also applies to questions that clash with our Q&A format by containing more than one distinct question?

Answer (score 2):

Just answering two out of 5 questions:

1- Check out [listings](http://ftp.snt.utwente.nl/pub/software/tex/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf) package.

3- check out [fancybox](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/fancybox) (`texdoc fancybox`).